# Magento : Get product URL In Export CSV

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

In magento how can i get product full url i.e. SITE_URL/PRODUCT URL in my product export CSV
I was googling for this stuff but can't find anything related to this....

i aslo dig the mage app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity and edit the follwing file Product.php but can find the URL_PATH colum to include the full path

Answer (score 1):

Well found it my self here is the solution 
I want to add the full url path to the product under the url_path column

1) Edit the file at path app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Entity 
2) At line number 630

```
 foreach ($validAttrCodes as &$attrCode) { // go through all valid attribute codes
```

3) this is giving all attributes to export
4) I inserted a condition

```
if($attrCode=='url_path'){
                            $attrValue = str_replace('index.php/','',Mage::getBaseUrl()).$attrValue;
                        }
```

5) Test my export and all was fine

At the end i know i hack the code but i don't have enough time to code the module nor even i know how to ... :-)

Comment: Instead of `str_replace` you can just do `Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB)`

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
            // Gets the current store's id
            $store = Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView();
            $product->setStoreId($store->getStoreId());

            //prepare csv contents
            $data = array();
            $data[] = $product['sku'];
            // this is the URL:
            $data[] = $product->getProductUrl();
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi in csv you cant get the site URL, because in magneto it automatically concatenates the site URL with the directory path. Can you please tell me why you need the site url in csv

Comment: This is my client requirement he need Full URl